# How to declare a composite key in JPA when one element of the key is an entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

There's a table

```
master
  id int primary key
```

and

```
detail
  master_id int references master(id),
  name string
  primary key (master_id, name)
```

with JPA entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "master")
class Master {
  @Id
  private int id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "detail")
@IdClass(DetailId.class)
class Detail {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "master_id")
  @Id
  Master master;

  @Id
  String name;
}
```

and an identity class

```
class DetailId {
  Master master;
  String name;
}
```

In runtime Hibernate is complaining that it can not set an `int` to a `Master` field initializing the `Detail` class.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you don't need to use `@Id` but something else. I think it's `@EmbeddedId`

Comment: See documentation such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html  `@Id` is totally usable in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `DetailId` you can't use an entity: you need to change `Master master` to `int master`. And you need to implement `Serializable`

```
class DetailId implements Serializable {

  int master;

  String name;

}
```

Comment: `DetailId` hasn't been annotated with `@Entity`, but thanks anyway

Comment: @BorisPavlović I mean that you need to change `Master master` to `int master`